# Reading from standard input in c++

Tags: c++, class, templates, matrix, cin

Edit: 
The main problem has been solved, the function almost works, now my problem is that I only want to read the line of numbers and when the user hits enter and as it is a temptale function it does not detect '\n'. So how could I solve this?

---

I have a temptale function which should read a matrix from the standard input (so I can only use cin >> to read) to a specific class.

The input would be like this:

```
4 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

The first two number represents the width, the second the height of the matrix. the other numbers in the line are the numbers in the matrix itself. (such as: it reads that it will be a 4x4 matrix. then it should read 4 numbers in a row an put it in the first line of the matrix. Then read again 4 numbers and ect...)
The imput should end when the user hits enter.
If the user didn't typed it in in the correct form (such as: not enough numbers) it should throw a message "Bad input" and start it from the beginning.

The sketch of the function would be something like this:

```
template <class T>
T& be_osztaly(){ // szabványos kimenetrõl beolvas egy mátrixot (ez fogjka a két mátrixot, az eredménymátrixot és ezek magasságait/szélességeit beolvasni és eltárolni).
    bool l = true;
    int szamlalo = 0;
    Peldamatrix<T> uj;
    T epp;
    while(szamlalo!=(uj.getx() * uj.gety()) ){
        cin >> epp;
        uj.setx(epp);
        cin >> epp;
        uj.sety(epp);

        l = true;
        while(l){
            for(int i=0;i<uj.getx();i++){
                for(int j=0;j<uj.gety();j++){
                    cin >> epp;
                    szamlalo++;
                    if(epp == '\n'){ // if (epp == endl)
                    l = false;
                    }
                if(szamlalo>(uj.getx() * uj.gety())) { throw "Ovextension!\n"; }
                uj.getaltombelem(i,j) = epp;
                }
            }
        }
        if(szamlalo<(uj.getx() * uj.gety())) {  throw "Not enought imput!!\n"; }
    }
    return &uj;
}
```

And the Peldamatrix class would be like this:

```
template <class S>
class Peldamatrix{
private:
    S* tomb[];
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    Peldamatrix(){
        tomb = new S*[s];
        for(int i=0;i<s;i++) { tomb[i] = new S[h]; }
    }

    S* operator[](const int index){
        return tomb[index];
    }

    int getx() {return x;}
    void setx(int v) {x=v;}

    int gety() {return y;}
    void sety(int v) {y=v;}

    S* gettomb() {return tomb;} // Ezt így lehet?
    S* getaltomb(const int index) {return tomb[index];}
    S getaltombelem(const int index, const int alindex) {return (tomb[index])[alindex];} // This seems to be not working but I haven't figured out how to yet

    Peldamatrix& operator=(const Peldamatrix &kulso){ 
        if(this = &kulso) {return *this;}; másolni!
        tomb = kulso.gettomb();
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++) { tomb[i] = kulso.getaltomb(i); } 
        x = kulso.getx();
        y = kulso.gety();
        return *this;
    }

    ~Peldamatrix(){
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++) { delete[] tomb[i]; }
        delete[] tomb;
    }
};
```

Comment: What did you try ? What did not work ?

Comment: What shall happen for example for this input: `22212345678901234567890123456789012345678901234`? You might have to rethink your input syntax.

Comment: You only showed one (very large) number as your input. Did you want to read individual digits from it? Should you be able to cope with dimensions and/or values greater than `9`?

Comment: @Quentin Thanks I tried something like this but it didnt work

http://pastebin.com/32kMLvjX

Comment: @Martze Good point, solved in thsi version (hopefully):

http://pastebin.com/32kMLvjX

Comment: @Useless Good point I tried to solve this by making spaces between the exact numbers like this: 4 4 1 1 1 ... but this didn't want to work with cin, but i think the solution should be close like this.

Comment: OK, so what was the actual problem? Did it fail to compile? Did it compile but do the wrong thing? I can't see an answerable question here as it stands.

Comment: If you control the input, then yes, by all means, separate your numbers by white space and use plain cin.

Comment: It looks like you have decided to use spaces between the numbers, which is a sensible choice. Do you still have a problem? If so, please update your question so that it reflects the current state of your problem (use the edit button rather than the comments feature).

Comment: @Useless Now it works but it has a problem reading '\n' if the <class T> is not char, just simply not reads as \n

Comment: @n.m. Thanks for the advice, I'm pretty new here :)